# how to use kill SIGUSR2 in bash?

Tags: linux, shell, kill

I use iptraf to monitor the network traffic in linux, and the shell command is(make iptraf running in background):

```
iptraf -s eth0 -f -B -L ./traffic.dat
```

if I want to get the result, I have to stop iptraf first, so I use the shell command:

```
kill -SIGUSR2 $pid
```

however, I could not stop iptraf if I move these shell commands into a bash script file(net.sh), and I get an error:

```
kill: SIGUSR2: invalid signal specification
```

I use 'kill -l' in the script file(net.sh), and I find there is no parameter which name is SIGUSR2. and I would get nothing if I use USR2 or -9.

the complete script file is:

```
    iptraf -s eth0 -f -B -L ./temp.txt
    pid=`ps -ef | grep iptraf | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`
    kill -USR2 $pid
    cat temp.txt
```

I get nothing after these commands.

what shoud I do if I want to get the result?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`SIGUSR2` is architecture depended and can have a value out of `31`, `12`  or `17`. This is described in [`man 7 signal`](http://sigusr2.net/page/man.html). You'll have to find out which value is appropriate for your system. Usually this is done by having a look into:

```
/usr/include/asm/signal.h
```

On my system - Ubuntu 12.04 AMD 64 - it has a value of `12`:

```
#define SIGUSR2     12
```

Once you know the proper numeric value for `SIGUSR2` on your system, you can send this signal using:

```
kill -SIGNO PID
# In this case
kill -12 PID
```

Answer (score 9):

On my Linux box it works.

I ran an infinite loop (pid = 4574), then I ran

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -l | grep USR2
kill -SIGUSR2 4574
```

*kill -l* has showed the signal and *kill -SIGUSR2* has sent the signal (killing the process).

Check if you are running Bash or some other shell (e.g., dash, busybox, etc.)

Comment: thank you very much, but it does not work on my linux box. and I still get the error "kill: SIGUSR2: invalid signal specification". maybe this error has something to do with the linux environment?

Comment: @Mark  It has got to do with the SIG prefix.  Please run it without the prefix and check

Answer (score 7):

Cross-platform way to do this: use `-s` without the `SIG` prefix. E.g.,:

`kill -s USR2 $pid`

This seems to work on both MacOS and linux.

Comment: My Yocto build, which is essentially BusyBox, also uses the POSIX format

Comment: It also works without -s flag but shouldnt have the SIG prefix